# R- Stats::Filter, Error in if (many_rows)

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I have some time series data:

```
x <- seq(1,300)
```

I want to use the filter function from stats:

```
f <- function(x, n=5){ 
      return(stats::filter(x, rep(1/n,n), sides=2))
}
f(x) # ERROR
```

When I call the function, i get the following Error:

```
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in if (many_rows) {: Argument has length 0

Traceback:
1. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2. tryCatch(withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler), error = outer_handler)
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
6. withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler)
7. repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
8. repr_text.ts(obj)
9. repr_ts_generic(obj, repr_text.matrix, ...)
10. repr_func(m, ..., rows = nrow(m), cols = ncol(m))
11. ellip_limit_arr(obj, ...)
12. arr_partition(a, rows, cols)
```

Any ideas? What does the traceback mean?

Comment: If you add the data in var `x`, then it'll be possible to reproduce the error as well as provide an alternative solution.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Can you edit your post adding the output of `dput(x)`? That's what I mean. If you want additional info on how to write a reproducible question  have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Instead of doing  ```f(x)``` do ```dput(x)``` and edit your question with the output. Or do ```f(1:10)``` and see if you get the same error

Comment: same error with x <- seq(1:300)

Comment: This doesn't produce an error on my system. It generates outputs that goes like `Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 300 
Frequency = 1 ...`  What happens if you run the function as `f(seq(5))`?

Comment: same error. I'm using this in jupyter notebook. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes, it could. I have never seen this specific error in R and "rich displaying" sounds like something a jupyter notebook might do.

Comment: solved by: install.packages(c('IRkernel', 'IRdisplay', 'repr'))